# Clicking on Div A triggers Div B and removes siblings of Div B

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a open-container div which contains thumbnails. If the user clicks on that thumbnail div then a div named box with the same index will appear.

So basically I have the following structure:

```
<div id="open-container">
  <div class="boxA-open"></div>
  <div class="boxB-open"></div>
  <div class="boxC-open"></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="profile"></div>
  <div class="data">
    <h1>Ipsum Lorum</h1>
    <h2>Ipsum Lorum</h2>
    <p>Ipsum Lorum</p>   
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="profile"></div>
  <div class="data">
    <h1>Ipsum Lorum</h1>
    <h2>Ipsum Lorum</h2>
    <p>Ipsum Lorum</p>   
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="profile"></div>
  <div class="data">
    <h1>Ipsum Lorum</h1>
    <h2>Ipsum Lorum</h2>
    <p>Ipsum Lorum</p>   
  </div>
</div>
```

To be honest I have not tried anything yet as I am not sure how to set the required connection between the divs.

My initial solution was setting 3 click events for each box-open class and target the boxes using nth-of-type. Writing the same code 3 times is not so elegant though.

The opacity of the divs is set to 0. Will be set to 1 if a box becomes visible or "will appear".

For user j08691:

```
$('div.box-open').click(function () {
    var timeline = new TimelineMax({paused:true});
    timeline.to($('.box').eq($(this).index()), 3,  {left:'6%', ease:Back.easeInOut})
    timeline.play();
})
```

Comment: No need to make three same code. My suggestion, put data attribute on each box with the name that linked to the class boxA,boxB etc

Comment: _"will appear"_ ? inside of  clicked `div` ?

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali I was thinking about that too. I was reading about Data-Attributes today but im not really sure how to do this in my context. I know how to set the data-attribute but that is about it.

Comment: @guest271314 the opacity of those 3 divs are set to 0. The opacity will be set to 1 for the respective div.

Comment: @Daniels Yes that what i thought. See my answer. As an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using this snippet of jQuery:

```
$('div.box-open').click(function () {
    $('.box').hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn();
})
```

And changing your container div classes to just `box-open`

```js
$('div.box-open').click(function () {
    $('.box').hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn();
})
```

```css
.box {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="open-container">
    <div class="box-open">A</div>
    <div class="box-open">B</div>
    <div class="box-open">C</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="profile"></div>
    <div class="data">
         <h1>Ipsum Lorum 1</h1>

         <h2>Ipsum Lorum</h2>

        <p>Ipsum Lorum</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="profile"></div>
    <div class="data">
         <h1>Ipsum Lorum 2</h1>

         <h2>Ipsum Lorum</h2>

        <p>Ipsum Lorum</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="profile"></div>
    <div class="data">
         <h1>Ipsum Lorum 3</h1>

         <h2>Ipsum Lorum</h2>

        <p>Ipsum Lorum</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I actually use greensock for animating so what I got is: $('div.box-open').click(function () {
 var timeline = new TimelineMax({paused:true});
 timeline.to($('.box').eq($(this).index()), 3,  {left:'6%', ease:Back.easeInOut})
 timeline.play();
})

Comment: @Daniels _"I actually use greensock for animating "_  ; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Does this solution solve Question ?

Comment: Hey, it worked. I had to make some changes to the original code of yours.

Comment: The only thing what Im wondering is, what if I also wanted to target the children box?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can be interested by this jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/syahrasi/Us8uc/

I think it's exactlly what you try to do, with a different layout.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tabs-menu a").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().addClass("current");
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("current");
        var tab = $(this).attr("href");
        $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");
        $(tab).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".open-container div").on("click", function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $("div.box")[index].show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it like this that you want.

HTML code

```
<div id="open-container">
 <div class="boxA-open">a</div>
 <div class="boxB-open">b</div>
 <div class="boxC-open">c</div>
</div>

<div class="box" data-box="boxA-open" style="display:none">
 <div class="profile"></div>
 <div class="data">
  <h1>Ipsum Lorum A</h1>
  <h2>Ipsum Lorum</h2>
  <p>Ipsum Lorum</p>   
  </div>
 </div>

<div class="box" data-box="boxB-open" style="display:none">
 <div class="profile"></div>
 <div class="data">
  <h1>Ipsum Lorum B</h1>
  <h2>Ipsum Lorum</h2>
  <p>Ipsum Lorum</p>   
 </div>
```

```
<div class="box" data-box="boxC-open" style="display:none">
  <div class="profile"></div>
   <div class="data">
   <h1>Ipsum Lorum C</h1>
   <h2>Ipsum Lorum</h2>
   <p>Ipsum Lorum</p>   
</div>
</div>
```

Js Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.boxA-open, .boxB-open, .boxC-open').on('click', function(){
    var class_name = $(this).attr('class');
    $('.box').each(function(i,e){
      if($(this).data('box')==class_name){
        $(this).show();
      }
      else{
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
    //console.log
  });
});
```

Working example

[Working example plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sZXLT9hNqLeHAWP9jLvR?p=preview)